# Why does PyDev 7.5 erroneously detect duplicated signatures with typing.overload?

Tags: python, overloading, pydev, typing

Here is a short code written in Python 3.7

```
from typing import overload, Tuple

class Cursor:
    # (let's forget about the contructor)

    @overload
    def move(self, dx: Tuple[int, int]) -> None:
        ...
    def move(self, dx:int, dy: int = None) -> None:
        # here comes the code that modifies the x and y coordinates
        # of the cursor according to the type of argument dx
```

In eclipse 2020-03, using PyDev 7.5, the second definition of `move()` is marked as a duplicated signature error. Meanwhile, when implemented, code runs correctly with no error/warning detected by the Python 3.7 interpreter.

When visiting the PyDev GitHub repository, a duplication checker seems to have been implemented and tested. For instance, see DuplicationChecker.java ([https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/master/plugins/com.python.pydev.analysis/src/com/python/pydev/analysis/visitors/DuplicationChecker.java](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/tree/master/plugins/com.python.pydev.analysis/src/com/python/pydev/analysis/visitors)) and function `testNoDuplicateOnTypingOverride()` at end of https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/master/plugins/org.python.pydev/tests_analysis/com/python/pydev/analysis/OccurrencesAnalyzerPy36Test.java.

But any added signature after the first typing-overloaded one is still detected by PyDev as a duplicated signature.

--> Is there any way to get rid of these erroneous "error marks" in eclipse?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PyDev, but I have some experience other type checkers and `overload`. The preferred approach is to define every possible argument combination as an `@overload` function stub, and write the actual function without type annotations. In your case, you'd probably need another stub: `def move(self, dx: int, dy: int) -> None:`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. With PyDev, any additional overloaded signature is marked as an error. This is the case with your proposed solution.

Comment: An unsatisfying solution is to set PyDev preferences. In eclipse, via menu `Window > Preferences > PyDev > Editor > Code Analysis`, tab `Others`, radio buttons group `Duplicated signature`. Check the `Ignore` radio button. But this does not solve the PyDev issue and may create other ones (i.e. true duplicate signatures no more detected in editor but only at run-time).